# While receiving date in firebase getting so much of junk files in database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

continuously junk file is creating automatically while i am pushing the data to the firebase

This is my code that pushing data to firebase

```
DatabaseReference callLogReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(CREHISTORY_URL);

String key = callLogReference.push().getKey();
callLogReference.child(key).setValue(callInfo);
```

Below image shows that how im getting data in firebase 
[image: This the what i am getting in firebase database]

Olease give the solution that not to get any junk file in the firebase database

Comment: The data you show is the result of two calls to `push().setValue(...)`. I'm not sure how the data relates to the code you showed though. Did you call the code twice? Did you want the properties in the two push ID nodes to be merged? And what is `callInfo`?

Comment: callInfo is the model class that i am pushing to the firebase. only one time i am pushing the data but in firebase junk is creating

Comment: Firebase doesn't automatically create nodes. If you have two nodes with a push ID, you're calling `push().setValue(...)` twice.

Comment: push().setValue(...) is calling only one time. and main thing is what ever the junk is creating in firebase it is not exactly how model "CallInfo" .It is creating with random variables of model class

Comment: Firebase does not automatically create any of this data. If the second structure looks different, you have code in your app or elsewhere that creates that different structure. It is impossible to say where that happens from the code you shared, so there isn't a lot we can do to help.